# How to properly set up a subdirs project with separate App and Qt Quick Test?

Tags: qt, unit-testing, qml

I am struggling with a proper setup for my new project. I am trying to incorporate unit tests for both C++ and QML elements, but I am really stuck at configuring the QML part.

I have already read [Qt Quick Test docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquicktest-index.html) but it did not help me to understand the very basics of subdirs project with test projects inside it. First of all, I have read that there should be separeate projects for both the source code of my **main app** and my **test app**.

How am I supposed to import Qt Quick components from my **main app** to a **test app** *tst_unittest.qml* file so I can test it's behaviour?

What I mean is something like this:

```
// tst_unittest.qml

import QtQuick 2.0
import QtTest 1.0

//some kind of import here?

TestCase {
    name: "UnitTests"

    ComponentToTest{
        id: entityToTest
    }

    function test_case() {
        compare(entityToTest.funcToTest(), false, "funcToTest unit test")
    }
}
```

My project tree looks like this:

```
-subdirs_project
|---subdirs_project.pro
|
|---main_app
|   |---main_app.pro
|   |---ComponentToTest.qml
|
|---test_app
|   |---test_app.pro
|   |---tst_unittests.qml
```

And my *test_app.pro*:

```
CONFIG += warn_on qmltestcase

TEMPLATE = app

DISTFILES += \
    tst_unittests.qml

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp

IMPORTPATH += \
    $$PWD/../main_app/ComponentToTest.qml
```

Is this at least somewhere near how it's supposed to look like or should I just trash it and make it in another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to configure my project and run all tests, so I think it's best to write about it here for all of the future folks that may need this. I am not going to paste here content of each and every file, but I am posting the most important ones that made me some troubles. For example, `testentity.cpp` and `testentity.h` are just regular source and header files for a simple C++ class, and I don't think explaining qml components is needed here. If any file is not described below you can assume it was okay from the very begining and Qt Creator made it all by itself or the changes are just trivial.

**FILE ORGANIZATION:**

```
.
├── ExampleProject
│   ├── ExampleProject.pro
│   ├── controls
│   │   ├── another_module
│   │   │   ├── testentity.cpp
│   │   │   └── testentity.h
│   │   ├── example_module
│   │   │   ├── testclass.cpp
│   │   │   ├── testclass.h
│   │   │   ├── testsubject.cpp
│   │   │   └── testsubject.h
│   │   ├── components
│   │   │   ├── applayout
│   │   │   │   ├── LayoutComponent.qml
│   │   │   │   └── SideMenu.qml
│   │   │   └── controls
│   │   │       └── PositioningDummy.qml
│   │   ├── controls.pro
│   │   ├── main.cpp
│   │   ├── main.qml
│   │   └── qml.qrc
│   ├── tests_cpp
│   │   ├── main.cpp
│   │   ├── tests_cpp.pro
│   │   ├── tst_controls.cpp
│   │   ├── tst_controls.h
│   │   ├── tst_layout.cpp
│   │   └── tst_layout.h
│   └── tests_qt_quick
│       ├── main.cpp
│       ├── tests_qt_quick.pro
│       ├── tst_controls.qml
│       └── tst_layout.qml
└── README.md
```

**mainprojectfile.pro**

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs

SUBDIRS += \
    controls \
    tests_cpp \
    tests_qt_quick
```

**tests_cpp.pro**

```
QT += testlib
QT -= gui

CONFIG += qt console warn_on depend_includepath testcase
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES +=  tst_controls.cpp \
    main.cpp \
    tst_layout.cpp

HEADERS += \
    tst_controls.h \
    tst_layout.h

# 1) Define each module as INCDIR_MODULE_NAME
# 2) Add INCDIR_MODULE_NAME to INCLUDEPATH
# 3) Add each of the classes you want to test into HEADERS and SOURCES

INCDIR_EXAMPLE_MODULE = ../controls/example_module
INCDIR_ANOTHER_MODULE = ../controls/another_module

INCLUDEPATH += \
    $$INCDIR_EXAMPLE_MODULE \
    $$INCDIR_ANOTHER_MODULE

SOURCES += \
    $$INCDIR_EXAMPLE_MODULE/testclass.cpp \
    $$INCDIR_EXAMPLE_MODULE/testsubject.cpp \
    $$INCDIR_ANOTHER_MODULE/testentity.cpp \

HEADERS += \
    $$INCDIR_EXAMPLE_MODULE/testclass.h \
    $$INCDIR_EXAMPLE_MODULE/testsubject.h \
    $$INCDIR_ANOTHER_MODULE/testentity.h
```

**tests_cpp/main.cpp**

```
#include <QTest>

#include "tst_layout.h"
#include "tst_controls.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int status = 0;

    Tst_Layout tst_layout;
    status |= QTest::qExec(&tst_layout, argc, argv);

    Tst_Controls tst_controls;
    status |= QTest::qExec(&tst_controls, argc, argv);

    return status;
}
```

**tests_cpp/tst_layout.h**

```
#ifndef TST_LAYOUT_H
#define TST_LAYOUT_H

#include <QtTest>

// include class from our controls project
#include "testentity.h"

class Tst_Layout : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Tst_Layout(QObject *parent = nullptr);

private slots:

    void initTestCase();
    void cleanupTestCase();

    void test_case1();
};

#endif
```

**tests_qt_quick.pro**

```
CONFIG += warn_on qmltestcase

TEMPLATE = app

DISTFILES += \
    tst_controls.qml \
    tst_layout.qml

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp
```

**tests_qt_quick/tst_layout.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtTest 1.12

import "../controls/components/applayout" as AppLayout
import "../controls/components/controls" as Controls

TestCase {
    name: "Layout"

    function initTestCase() {}

    function cleanupTestCase() {}

    // please bear in mind that test functions below are not my actual tests
    // they are here only to show the very basics of how to set up Qt Quick tests

    function test_layoutEntityReturnTrue() {
        verify(layoutEntity.returnTrue(),("Put some test fail message here."))
    }

    function test_sideMenuReturnTrue() {
        verify(layoutEntity.returnTrue(),("Put some test fail message here."))

    }

    AppLayout.LayoutComponent {
        id: layoutEntity
    }

    AppLayout.SideMenu {
        id: sideMenuEntity
    }
}
```